# invalid syntax function run api

Tags: python

i want to change parameter by input
but it doesn't work
`File "<string>", line 3 def getbotnoi(message) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

```
import requests
message = input("What do you want")
def getbotnoi(message)
    undefined=message
    url = "https://openapi.botnoi.ai/botnoi/ecommerce?keyword=; +undefined  
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MTIwOTM5MjcsImlkIjoiNTJjYTJjODgtNDI2Ny00ZDEwLTkwNzktYmE4MGMxZWNhMzQ5IiwiaXNzIjoiZnloRHFJV1Npb3R4YmN3MkI4amZ5dUJBdUNHdFRLcm4iLCJuYW1lIjoiMTQzMy4wOCIsInBpYyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcHJvZmlsZS5saW5lLXNjZG4ubmV0LzBoR1diUjVwYTVHSGhmS3pCcDdReG5MMk51RmhVb0JSNHdKMGxXR0h3dlFFMTJIVjRvWVJoVlNuOV9RMHh4SFZncE1VNEhHM3A1UWgxdyJ9.wfEGlqTBL1YQMsKWOEunptFk3mudSINF0ohdjTraCD0'
}
    response = requests.request("Get", url, headers=headers)
    if response['intent'] ==  "ขอเวลาปิดทำการ"
        return ไม่มีวันปิดครับ

print(getbotnoi(message))
```

Comment: Try: `return "ไม่มีวันปิดครับ"`

Comment: You are missing a `:` on line 3 when defining your function. Your also missing colon in your if statment and missing a closing `"` on some strings.

Comment: `:` u missed this in `def getbotnoi(message)`

Comment: Remove  the `}`, and end the function def with a : `def getbotnoi(message):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems with your code.

1. Missing `:` with function definition and the `if` condition
2. Missing quotes with the statement initializing `url` and the returned string
3. You need to get the `json` data from the returned response

Try this working one:

```
import requests
message = input("What do you want")
def getbotnoi(message):
    undefined=message
    url = "https://openapi.botnoi.ai/botnoi/ecommerce?keyword=;" + undefined  
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MTIwOTM5MjcsImlkIjoiNTJjYTJjODgtNDI2Ny00ZDEwLTkwNzktYmE4MGMxZWNhMzQ5IiwiaXNzIjoiZnloRHFJV1Npb3R4YmN3MkI4amZ5dUJBdUNHdFRLcm4iLCJuYW1lIjoiMTQzMy4wOCIsInBpYyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcHJvZmlsZS5saW5lLXNjZG4ubmV0LzBoR1diUjVwYTVHSGhmS3pCcDdReG5MMk51RmhVb0JSNHdKMGxXR0h3dlFFMTJIVjRvWVJoVlNuOV9RMHh4SFZncE1VNEhHM3A1UWgxdyJ9.wfEGlqTBL1YQMsKWOEunptFk3mudSINF0ohdjTraCD0'}
    response = requests.request("Get", url, headers=headers).json()
    if response['intent'] ==  "ขอเวลาปิดทำการ":
        return "ไม่มีวันปิดครับ"

print(getbotnoi(message))
```